# Проблема с приемом данных JSON в PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

В общем написал скрипт который собирает все введенное из формы, и посылает данные в PHP. Но тут проблема массив $_POST  пуст.

пользуюсь jquery-3.2.1.js.

вот сам скрипт и скрин.

```
$(function(){
    var button=$("button");
    button.click( function (){
        var data = $("form").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "registration.php",
            data: {'data':data},
            success: function () {
                alert(data);
                console.log(data);
            },
        });
    });

});


echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $_POST );
echo "</pre>";
```

В общем в консоли есть объект, а в PHP в массиве пост пусто. Что я делаю не так? Кто знает подскажите?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: прием данных успешен]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

данные принялись но ка ктогда дальше с ними работать если они сериализованными приходят?????? По отдельности понятно. А вот сериализованными?

Comment: а вы хоть проверяли данные из формы до отправки в PHP  ?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом проверяли?, CALLBACK  функция success выдает алерт и в консоле есть данные а вот в PHP массив POST пуст(

Comment: можете показыать код из registration.php ?

Comment: echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $_POST );
echo "</pre>";

Comment: Судя по комментарию, что вы в консоли видите переданные данные, вы проверяете массив в PHP просто на прямую, в браузере, открыв registration.php файл, и что вы там ожидаете увидеть? Когда по ссылке открываете файл вы ничего не передаете, ни параметров $_GET ни $_POST, и он не будет знать когда вы там, чего вы ему передавали в ajax, и ясное дело, он будет пуст

Comment: @Bookin А как же тогда проверить что приходит или не приходит в PHP?

Comment: Ну вы сами ответили на вопрос же, в консоле вы видете что передалли, так же в вкладке Network можно увидеть что отправляет запрос. Хотите без запроса отработать файл, переключилитесь на $_GET параметры, и руками проверьте, можите использовать курл для запроса с POST параметрами, программа Postman как вариант, ну или xdebug (и подобные отладчики) делайте контрольные остановки.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман для того чтобы проверить ответ при AJAX запросе :
 success: function (result) {
console.log(result);
} 
и вы получите ответ

Comment: @Arsen он в вопросе привел и код пхп и код js и там и вардамп и консоль.

Comment: @Bookin вы об этом  console.log(data); ?

Comment: @Bookin Хорошо перефразирую как мне так принять данные в PHP что бы можно было дальше с ними работать?

Comment: @Arsen виноват, извиняюсь)

Comment: @ДимаПерильман а что вам сейчас мешает с ними работать $_POST обычный массив, работайте на здоровье.

Comment: @Bookin у меня пустой массив ; $_POST похоже, или нужно научить свой JS скрипт принимать данные обратно, Или перестать надеяться увидеть print_r($_POST) что то(.
В общем я не пойму где ошибка. далее по коду идет проверка , и работа с данными, данные шлются в базу, из базы достается и возвращются данные.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман Откройте консоль разработчика, откройте вкладку Network, найдите ваш запрос `registration.php`, откройте его и внизу посмотрите какие данные отправляются, а лучше добавьте скрин в вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Одностраничный пример:

```
<?php

if(!empty($_POST)){
    $data = $_POST;
    var_dump($data);

    $name = $data['name'];
    $other = $data['other'];

    var_dump($name, $other);
    return;
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var form = {'name':'some name', 'other':'data'};//$("form *").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "registration.php",
                data: form,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                },
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>Page opened</body>
</html>
```

- Каждый новый запрос к php файлу, не хранит информации о предыдущем, как вам ранее указали, открыть отдельно в браузере и сделать запрос в ajax будут разными запросами с разными данными.
- Как вам указали в callback функции вы упустили параметр который возвращает ответ от php файла - `success: function (result) {` - в переменной `result` вы получите то что ответит php на ваш ajax запрос.

Comment: var form = {'name':'some name', 'other':'data'};//$("form *").serialize();
так и у меня работает а вот на сериалайз пост не принемается( или как его принять при сериализации

Comment: в ответ на вот такой код 
$data=$_POST;
echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $data );
echo "</pre>";

$name=$data['name'];
$email=$data['email'];
$territory=$data['Territory'];

var_dump($name,$email,$territory);

приходит что /registration.php:13:null а это строка вардампа переменных.

registration.php:6:
array (size=0)
  empty

это строка данных масива. Но все по Network пришло.

Answer (score 0):

Вы делаете два запроса к registration.php - первый раз, когда просто загружаете страницу, и второй раз, когда отправляете Ajax-запрос.

В первом случае браузер, как обычно, отправляет GET-запрос, чтобы получить содержимое всей страницы. Во втором он асинхронно отправляет POST-запрос с полями вашей формы.

Ваша проблема заключается в том, что вы смотрите на результат первого запроса - то, что браузер получает в ответ на GET-запрос. Для того, чтобы получить ответ на второй вопрос, используйте callback-функцию success() в вашем коде:

```
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}
```

Эта функция вызывается при успешной отправке данных Ajax-запросом, и содержит строку с ответом сервера.

Чтобы в следующий раз не запутаться, я бы посоветовал сделать так, чтобы сервер не выводил содержимое $_POST, если это обычный GET-запрос, или отделил скрипт, который принимает POST-запрос, от скрипта, который показывает форму.